# Can I connect to an AWS RDS instance from a Batch Function via a peering VPC connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have 2 VPCs (A and B) which have a peering connection from A to B. VPC B contains an RDS instance (PostgreSQL) which is not publicly accessible, and cannot be. The RDS Security Group has ingress enabled on 5432 from the peering VPC CIDR block.

VPC A contains a Lambda which can connect to the database with no problem. It also contains a Batch job running on EC2 which *cannot* connect to the database with the following error:

`connection to server at "mydatabase.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (10.50.0.32), port 5432 failed: timeout expired`

Given that the Security Group appears to be correctly configured - the Lambda can connect after all, what could I be missing with the Batch configuration?

DNS resolution is not actually enabled, it was resolving without it enabled. However, enabling it made no difference either.

Comment: Hi James, what do you mean by 'Batch Function'? That concept doesn't exist in AWS. Do you mean a Batch job that runs on EC2/Fargate/EKS?

Comment: Thanks, I clarified that it's a Batch job on EC2

Comment: Is DNS resolution enabled for your VPC peering connections? I think yes since I can see `10.50.0.32` being resolved but want to double check as it's been a while I've peered VPCs 

Comment: It isn't enabled actually, it was resolving without it despite what the docs led me to believe. I did try with and without DNS resolution and it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the need to map subnets to route tables in both directions - this solved my problem.